# MySQL Connecter - Is it most efficient to keep a connection open for the lifetime of the data access layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, database

I have read that ASP.NET uses connection pooling to manage database connections so it is not inefficient to open and close database connections on a per request basis. I assume this for SQL Server. What about for MySQL using the .NET connecter?

I am building a D.A.L. and I am basically wondering if I should open and close db connections in each function or if I should keep a connection open until the class is cleaned up and use Disposable/Finalize to ensure the db connection is closed.

Comment: As flesh suggested open and close connections at method level since opening a connection in .NET really involves fetching one from the pool and closing one means releasing it back to the pool. Therefore you should "request" a connection as late as possible and "release" a connection as soon as possible. If a pooled connection isnt available to service your request only then is one created and opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always go for pooling if you can - the largest cost in (simple) database access is always opening and closing a connection.

The NET Connector supports [pooling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html). And take note:

> it is best to let the connection pooling system manage all connections. You should not create a globally accessible instance of MySqlConnection and then manually open and close it. This interferes with the way the pooling works and can lead to unpredictable results or even exceptions